# Regex to fetch substring from a string

Tags: regex, string, replace, notepad++

I am using notepad++ and trying to find/replace occurrences of a particular word in an XML file with another word inside a particular tag.

For example:
XML file contains

```
<alerts>
     <ccEmails>abc@example.com,xyz@example.com</ccEmails>
     <toEmails>mnp@example.com</toEmails>            
</alerts>
```

I need to replace **example** with **myexample** present inside`<ccEmails>` but **not** inside`<toEmails>`

I tried `ccEmails.*(example).*ccEmails` at https://regex101.com/r/Q8UB6a/1, and it is returning only last occurrence. Also, I am not able to replace the string with another there.

When I tried this in notepad++, I am getting all the string inside `<ccEmails>`

[image]

Could you please help me in find/replace the substring contained within particular tags. Please let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use the Find and replace dialog, you need to use a `\G` based regex like

```
(?:<ccEmails>|\G(?!^))[^<]*?\K\bexample\b
```

and replace with `myexample`. See an [online regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pMpzIj/2)

**Details**:

- `(?:<ccEmails>|\G(?!^))`  - either `<ccEmails>` or the end of the last successful match
- `[^<]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `<` as few as possible
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
  -`\bexample\b` - whole word `example`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(<ccEmails>[^<>]+@)example\.` with `\1myexample.` and doing a replace all. The replace-all will need to be done two or more times as each pass only changes one `example` within the required strings.